# Group stage draw for teams

Tags: mysql, sql

I was watching UEFA champions league Draw. And the presenter said that the computer will show us for every team, the teams that can play against in Round 16, with condition:

1. Teams of same country can't play against each other in round 16;
2. Teams of the same group can't play against each other in round 16.

I made table with following columns:

- Team
- Group
- Country

I want to use SQL codes where I put in a procedure the name of the team and it shows teams eligible to play against.
I tried a lot, but can't create the logic of the code, it is little bit hard to my SQL knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a self join on your table where the group and the country do not equal. Joins can use other operators than =.

```
select t1.*,t2.team as opponent, t2.group as opponentgroup, t2.country as opponent country
from table t1 inner join table t2 on t1.country<>t2.country and t1.group<>t2.group
```